# Issue when trying to run hello world

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

When I try to run my Android app on the AVD, I get the main screen but it's not changeable. I mean it's still like this, I wait for it but nothing has changed.

[image]

Comment: It looks like your emulator is running but the eclipse plugin is either not attached to it or you're missing the run step.

Answer (score 0):

Heve you tried to run AVD from SDK manager?

Comment: How is that, can you explain me please?

Comment: Go to Eclipse -> Window -> AVD Manager -> select your AVD and then click start button. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the AVD from AVD Manager. In eclipse, go to Window -> AVD Manager -> Select your AVD and click on start button. If this is the first time you are running the AVD, it might take sometime to boot.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Hello, World tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html):

```
The Eclipse plugin makes it easy to run your applications:

Select Run > Run.
Select "Android Application".
```

The eclipse plugin will attach itself to the emulator running and run your app.